# Двойной вызов, PHP

Tags: php, методы

Приношу огромное извинение за качество кода, ну уж совсем новичек, но вот ума не приложу, почему метод в классе отрабатывает 2 раза, т.е. в данном случает заносятся сразу 2 записи в базу? Думаю решение элементарное, подскажите если знаете, буду благодарен.

```
<?php

    class Record {

        var $server_name;
        var $page;
        var $bot_name;
        var $bot_ip;
        var $created;

        private function query($query) {
            static $hostname = "";
            static $username = "";
            static $password = "";
            static $database = "";

            try {
                $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);

                $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

                //$db = null;

                return $db->query($query);

            }
            catch(PDOException $e) {
                return $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        private function matchBot($user_agent) {
            $engines = array( //Задаём имена известных ботов
                array('Aport', 'Aport robot'),
                array('Google', 'Google'),
                array('msnbot', 'MSN'),
                array('Rambler', 'Rambler'),
                array('Yahoo', 'Yahoo'),
                array('AbachoBOT', 'AbachoBOT'),
                array('accoona', 'Accoona'),
                array('AcoiRobot', 'AcoiRobot'),
                array('ASPSeek', 'ASPSeek'),
                array('CrocCrawler', 'CrocCrawler'),
                array('Dumbot', 'Dumbot'),
                array('FAST-WebCrawler', 'FAST-WebCrawler'),
                array('GeonaBot', 'GeonaBot'),
                array('Gigabot', 'Gigabot'),
                array('Lycos', 'Lycos spider'),
                array('MSRBOT', 'MSRBOT'),
                array('Scooter', 'Altavista robot'),
                array('AltaVista', 'Altavista robot'),
                array('WebAlta', 'WebAlta'),
                array('IDBot', 'ID-Search Bot'),
                array('eStyle', 'eStyle Bot'),
                array('Mail.Ru', 'Mail.Ru Bot'),
                array('Scrubby', 'Scrubby robot'),
                array('Yandex', 'Yandex'),
                array('YaDirectBot', 'Yandex Direct')
                );

            foreach ($engines as $engine) {
                if (strstr($user_agent, $engine[0]))
                    return($engine[1]);
            }
            return (false);
        }

        function record($user_agent) {
            if($name = $this->matchBot($user_agent)) {

                $this->server_name = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
                $this->page = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
                $this->bot_name = $name;
                $this->bot_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                $this->created = date('Y-m-d h:m:s');
                @$response = $this->query("INSERT INTO sites (name) VALUES ('$this->server_name')");
                @$response = $this->query("SELECT id FROM sites WHERE name='$this->server_name'");
                $result = $response->fetch();
                $site_id = $result['id'];
                @$response = $this->query("INSERT INTO stats (site_id, page, bot_name, bot_ip, created) 
                                        VALUES ('$site_id', '$this->page', '$this->bot_name', '$this->bot_ip', '$this->created')");
            }
        }

    }

    $user_agent = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    $rec = new Record($user_agent);
    $rec->record($user_agent);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function record($user_agent)

совпадает с названием класса, т.е это является конструктором класса который вызывается при new Request

потом вы еще раз, уже явно, вызываете этот метод, в следствии 2 записи.

ЗЫ: делать каждый раз коннект на каждый query не есть гуд.

Comment: Спасибо, не подумал бы, считал что названия методов и классов в разных регистрах не должны совпадать, с коннектом исправлюсь. Еще раз спасибо.